# Meaning of "has a ____ to it"

Tags: phrases, idioms, prepositions

People talking about how something will be perceived sometimes use the phrase "to it". For example people sometimes say "It will have a nice color to it." instead of just it will have a nice color. Or when something sounds nice someone says "It has a nice ring to it." What is the function of "to it" in these kinds of sentences?

Comment: D’you know, that’s actually a really good question. I can’t really describe in words what nuance of meaning it adds. The best way I can think of to describe it (and that’s not very good—it’s the kind of subjective, wishy-washy fluff that I hate because it will almost certainly mean different things to different people, and nothing at all to most) is that it creates a looser, more detached relationship between the object and the sound/colour/ring than just perceiving the latter as a property of the former. (Sometimes it’s just necessary, though: “It has a nice ring” doesn’t work at all.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet perhaps something 'having a nice ring to it' just has a nicer ring to it than it 'having a nice ring'...

Comment: @Spagirl Unless you're at an engagement party. ;-)

Comment: If something "has a nice ring" there is some suggestion that it is meant literally, about some form of circular band.  If it "has a nice ring to it" then the ambiguity is lost and it becomes clear the speaker means "ring" more onomatopoeically or as in the sense of "ringing a bell".  The relationship of this term to the physics of sound generation in a bell may be less clear.  The etymology of the word "ring" in the sense of literally ringing a bell is something I've not been able to uncover.  I found an SE question about the etymology of the metaphor, but it doesn't go beyond a literal bell.

Comment: "a nice color to it" isn't an idiom, but "nice ring to it" is. It means that the name, word or sound that has been attributed to something sounds especially pleasing or appropriate in some way.

Comment: Just a hunch. Perhaps it started as "(something) *gives* a nice __ to it", where *it* refers to the 'recipient' of the 'gift'. Then *gives* drifted to *has*, leaving *to it* hanging.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - it's a highly uninteresting question  :)  "has a nice ring to it" is a common phrase in English.  it is absolutely the norm in English that you take common phrases, them tweak them, substitute words, and so on.  (culminating in the "snowclone!" meme)  the phenomenon is so commonplace that the answer to the (zillions of questions like this) can only be "it's the most commonplace thing in English". (regarding the origin of the particular common phrase  "has a nice ring to it" - I mean, ok, what's the origin?)

Comment: @DarrenRinger "has a ring" has utterly no connection to the things you put on your finger.  it means the **BELL** has a nice ring to it, a nice sound.

Comment: @Fattie I understand that, although I frequently hear it about the sound of a word/phrase and not a bell.  Ie, "that name has a nice ring to it".  Here's an example:  Let's say you open a jewelry store called "Fattie's Bling".  You hear somebody say "Fattie's Bling has a nice ring"... you don't know if they are talking about a literal ring you sell, or the name of the shop. However, if they say "Fattie's Bling has a nice ring to it" it is obvious they are referring to the name itself, not a product inside.

Comment: @Strawberry "to it" is not required for that idiom in general. One could say "I'm gonna name it 'Flabozz!' Yeah, that name has a nice ring!" and it would be a relatively less common phrasing, but not inappropriate at all.  Combined with my immediately prior comment, I see this as evidence that "to it" is mainly appended to a term in order to eliminate contextual ambiguity.

Comment: @darrenringer I can't comment on appropriateness, but in my universe, the phrase always includes "to it". Your name, for instance, has a nice ring to it.

Answer (score 70):

I would say that adding *to it* emphasizes **perception** of the thing, as opposed to an inherent quality of the thing.  In other words, it emphasizes or draws attention to a subject that observes or otherwise perceives or interacts with the thing.

The expression really refers to an **effect on the observer**.  In *a nice ring to it* the *ring[ing]* is not a quality of the thing but a feeling/thought that takes place in the observer.

Comment: Very good.  I think you might have captured it.  Like Janus Bahs Jacquet's comment, this is one of those things that you can feel a sense of, but it's had to translate into words.

Comment: ***Anything*** to back this up. I have downvoted it because I disagree. The construction does refer to the object being talked about.

Comment: @Clare: Of course it refers to the object being talked about. It's a question of nuance, connotation. Adding *to it* can *draw attention* to the subject's appreciation of the object. That does not mean that no attention is given to the object. There may be a ring coming from the object itself - there usually is (but there also may not be).

Answer (score 11):

It ***is*** a good question.
The *have `X` to it* construction reminds me of some constructions in other languages.

- Spanish *A mí no me gusta el cilantro.* 'I don't like cilantro'
  [literally *To me not me likes the cilantro*.]

Spanish has no transitive verb *like*, with the emotional perceiver as subject and perceived thing as object; instead, there is a flipped construction with *gustar*, which takes the perceiver (*me*) as **object**, and the perceived thing as **subject**. Adding *a mí* is optional and emphatic.

- German *Er hat sich die Hände gewaschen*. 'He washed his hands'
  [literally *He has to himself the hands washed*.
  *Sich* is the 3p dative-accusative reflexive pronoun]

German prohibits using some inalienably possessed body parts and other special terms as objects with possesors.  Instead, there is a reflexive dative construction, converting 'wash' into a verb with an indirect object.

In both of these constructions, there is a repetition of some NP, for some kind of pragmatic purpose like emphasis or taboo; and at least one of these NPs is typically a pronoun, just like the *have `X` to it* constructions.

This suggests to me that the *to it* construction (which doesn't have any common name I'm familiar with and doesn't seem to be in the literature yet) may be a work-around idiom for some deficiency in English. Which in turn suggests looking for how one says this in other languages.

And looking for other verbs than *have* (or *give*, which involves *have*) to try it with:

- *That has/gives a nice color to it.*
- **That paints a nice color to it*
- **That looks like a nice color to it*
- **It/That seems a nice color to it*
- **She wants a nice color to it*

And looking for other subject-object relations to try it with:

- *That has (quite) a kick/a smooth feel/an interesting rhythm to it.*
- *That has a top/a bottom/a door/a latch/4 sides/a real future to it.*
- **That has a steering wheel/new tires/an overhaul to it*
- **That has a missile launcher/a machine gun/armament to it*
- **That has my approval/his authorization/a license to it*

Comment: A mí no me gusta *el* cilantro

Comment: Literally _He has to himself the hands washed._ You can't tell whether _sich_ is accusative or dative, but in (e.g.) the first person, it is clearly dative:_Ich habe mir die Hände gewaschen._ (I wouldn't have mentioned this, but it is after all what your answer is about!)

Comment: No, it isn't an answer, but I don't think we're going to get one This is an interesting construction, but there isn't much known about it. And, for the record, apologies for my bad German and Spanish examples. Thank you all for your corrections.

Comment: I think if you want a really literal translation of "gustar" you should use "please" rather than "like" ("cilantro does not please me").

Comment: That's a good fit for the syntactic construction -- object experiencer and subject experienced thing -- but _please me_ doesn't have the idiomatic connotations of _I like_, not to speak of the Victorian scene it conjures up. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: I cannot talk about Spanish; but your German example is wrong. The translation does not form a proper English sentence, and the grammatical explanation is also incorrect. "It makes a nice colour to it" should be translated to German with "Das gibt eine gute Farbe (ab)".

Comment: @Casey The Spanish verb "gustar" may be translated as to like, to please, and even to love (both in liking sense and romantic sense), depending on context and emphasis.

Comment: The Spanish is not right. Should be "(To me) the cilantro does not please me". Kind of awkward in English.

Comment: @PabloStraub Quite so, but if you mean to literally translate the sense in which the thing being liked is the subject, rather than the object, "please" is really your only choice in English.

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest that when expressing something with "has a ___ to it" there is an implied sense of what the word "***aura***" means.

the ideas of **"radiating" or "emanating" a "feeling"**

A few definitions of "aura" might help.

> [***aura*** at Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aura)
>
> 1
>   a :  a distinctive atmosphere surrounding a given source
>
> *The place had an aura of mystery.*
>
> b :  a subtle sensory stimulus (such as an aroma)

and

> [***aura*** at Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/aura)
>
> 1.
>   a distinctive and pervasive quality or character; air; atmosphere:
>
> *an aura of respectability; an aura of friendliness.*
>
> 2.
>   a subtly pervasive quality or atmosphere seen as emanating from a person, place, or thing.

Answer (score 6):

The way I use '*a* has *b* to it' is as to express that there is a sense/feeling of *b* in *a*. For example, to me, '*the movie* has a *strong vibe* to it' says that there is a sense of a *'strong vibe'* in *the movie*. As to your example, '*it* has a *nice ring* to it' is effectively saying, 'there is a feeling of a *nice ring* in *it*'.

At other times, such as your example '*it* will have a *nice colour* to it' or the sentence '*this football player* has *got nice feet to him*', the *to it* part may stand for *aspect* instead of *sense/feeling*, so 'there is an aspect of *nice colour* in *it*', and 'there is an aspect of *having great feet* in *this football player'*.

P.S. In fact, having thought about it, the sentence 'it has a nice ring to it' may refer to either case depending on the context. For example, 'this phone has a nice ring to it' will probably fall into the second group.

Comment: Yeah, probably declaring the _b_ as a component to _a_ with _a_ as the subject.